# php comparing 2 co-ords

Tags: php, if-statement

I don't know why, but this doesn't seem to work.

Basically I want this to be true if the player1 `($playerX, $playerY)` is within one square from player2 `($rs[x], $rs[y])`

```
if (($rs[x] > $playerX-2 or $rs[x] < $playerX+2) && ($rs[y] > $playerY-2 or $rs[y] < $playerY+2)) {
    // code
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you replace with some test values, you might get:

```
if( (3 > 5 or 3 < 9) && (13 > 15 or 13 < 19))
```

Clearly, this is always true.

You should use `&&` instead of `or` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a case of replacing `or` with `and`. Here's a neater way of writing your if statement for bonus points:

```
if(abs($playerX - $rs[x]) < 2 && abs($playerY - $rs[y]) < 2) {
    // code
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions end up on true due to the OR operator

```
if (($rs[x] > $playerX-2 && $rs[x] < $playerX+2) && ($rs[y] > $playerY-2 && $rs[y] < $playerY+2)) {
   //your code
}
```